# How to update my git on kubuntu?

Tags: updates, git

In my kubuntu 20 I have :

```
git version 2.25.1
```

From my team-maneger I got notice that
I need to update my git to version 2.29 or upper
How can I do it correctly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use a `ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

> **PPA description**:
> The most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This will give you version `2.36.1` currently.

To revert to the version provided by Ubuntu, you can use `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:git-core/ppa
```